# Talend read file with comma separator

Tags: talend

I have .csv file and it looks like:

```
    "Account Number","Account","Payment Method","Account Status","State","Batch ID","Transaction Date","Payment Amount","Entered By"

 "00010792-8","Max Little","Credit Card","Active","NC","9155","9/3/2014","$70.85","Diane Barr"
 "00036360-0","Bill Miller","Cash","Active","NC","9164","9/3/2014","$181.46","Jennifer Lamar"
 "00045576-9","Lsw, Inc","Credit Card","Active","NC","9152","9/3/2014","$173.98","Daniel Sheets"
```

I try to load it with tFileInputDelimited.

In Component->Basic Settings, I choose  Field Separator: ","

Unfortunately, 3rd row Account column value looks like  "Lsw, Inc", contains the delimiter ","

How to read this file correctly, without splitting text values, that contains symbols "," into columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSV appears to be string quoted so it's just a matter of telling Talend that this is the case.

Thankfully this is pretty easy:

[image: tFileInputDelimited CSV options]

Ticking that "CSV options" box will bring up the options for escape characters and text enclosure. Your CSV appears to be fine with just using double quotes so I'd leave it as that unless you see any other peculiarities.